# AppleScript: how do I check which apps are playing audio?

Tags: applescript

I'm new to AppleScript and I'm trying to write a script that changes the volume in whatever app is playing audio [iTunes, Spotify, whatever].

Is there a way for AppleScript to check which apps are currently playing audio? I've searched for an answer to this but came up empty...

correction:
I found this link http://hypertext.net/2011/11/applescript-powermate-media-apps/

which has this script:

```
    --Define the lastPaused property and give it a default value
    property lastPaused : ""

    --Get current states of iTunes and Spotify
    tell application "iTunes" to set itunesState to (player state as text)
    tell application "Spotify" to set spotifyState to (player state as text)

    --Pause the active app; play the last-paused app
    if itunesState is equal to "playing" then
        tell application "iTunes" to playpause
        set lastPaused to "iTunes"
    else if spotifyState is equal to "playing" then
        tell application "Spotify" to playpause
        set lastPaused to "Spotify"
    else if ((itunesState is equal to "paused") and (lastPaused is equal to "iTunes")) then
        tell application "iTunes" to playpause
    else if ((spotifyState is equal to "paused") and (lastPaused is equal to "Spotify")) then
        tell application "Spotify" to playpause
    end if
```

so, this works for iTunes/Spotify but not for anything else playing audio.

can't applescript just check what app is playing audio and stop it [without having to hard code the app names?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: AppleScript can't do that as a generic solution

Comment: ok, good to know... thanks. you're 2 for 2 answering my questions!